# Custom data labels for charts with XlsxWriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to create a some of a complex chart using XlsxWriter, thus I need to add some data labels to my series. The problem is that the data labels I need are different from the series value.

Within Excel is something simple to do:

1)  right click format data labels

2) label contains: values from cells

3) I then select the cells I want and it creates the data labels

If there is any way to do this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature isn't supported since it wasn't part of the original Excel 2007 file format.

There is a feature request for this: [XlsxWriter/feature_request/343](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/343).